# Evento ao clicar num marcador do Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar  evento nos marcadores do Google Maps pra abrir uma janela de informações customizada, como um fragment, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

Use o método `setOnMarkerClickListener()`, do mapa,  para "setar" um [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) que terá o seu método`onMarkerClick()` chamado quando o usuário clicar nele.

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    }
```

O objecto recebido no parâmetro `marker` é o do Marker clicado.

Veja [Marker click events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#marker_click_events) na documentação.